# What's the right multiplier of the third icon in my storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

Look at the below snapshot, you can see the three icons on the viewController's view.

The left green icon's Multiplier is 1.27 , the center icon is 1, but I don't know the right yellow icon if is 1.66, I set 1.66 it looks fit, maybe some wispy offset. Some friend can tell me the right Multiplier?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the two side icons to be equidistant from the center. This is clever!

I think your multipliers should be .33 and 1.66, respectively. That is .66 less than, and then .66 greater than, the center.

If you are stuck to .27 on the left one (assuming your question has a typo and that it's not 1.27), use 1.73 on the right.

So for the item on the right and left, you want the constraint to read like this, respectively:

right-icon-center-x to be 1.66 * superview-center-x
left-icon-center-x to be .33 * superview-center-x

[image: Balanced icons in slim superview]
[image: Balanced icons in wide superview]